# SSH issue on Ubuntu Mate / Raspberry PI

Tags: ssh, openssh, ubuntu-mate, raspberrypi

I keep have an issue with SSH

I always have this message when trying to connect :

```
Connection closed by 192.168.1.10 port 22
```

When I check the SSH status

```
 ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab    Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-01-01 23:17:08 GMT; 57min ago  Process: 804 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS  Main PID: 487 (sshd)    CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─487 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Jan 01 23:17:14 kevin-desktop sshd[487]: Server listening on :: port
22. Jan 02 00:14:09 kevin-desktop sshd[2078]: error: key_load_public: invalid format Jan 02 00:14:09 kevin-desktop sshd[2078]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/s Jan 02 00:14:09 kevin-desktop sshd[2078]: error: key_load_public: invalid format Jan 02 00:14:09 kevin-desktop sshd[2078]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/s Jan 02 00:14:09 kevin-desktop sshd[2078]: error: key_load_public: invalid format Jan 02 00:14:09 kevin-desktop sshd[2078]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/s Jan 02 00:14:09 kevin-desktop sshd[2078]: error: key_load_public: invalid format Jan 02 00:14:09 kevin-desktop sshd[2078]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/s Jan 02 00:14:09 kevin-desktop sshd[2078]: fatal: No supported key exchange algor
```

Comment: This sounds more like a rasbian issue than an Ubuntu one - does anything here help? --> [Headless SSH Not Initializing Properly](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=168371)

Comment: Are you ever logged in? or is it never allowing the connection?
can you show verbose output of ssh? `ssh -v <user>@<address>`

Comment: Noticing it says it can't find the key `/etc/s`...  Looks to me like you need to check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure you haven't accidentally messed that up, or uncommented an invalid `#HostKey` line.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this myself, it's when the host keys get corrupted. You can reset them by doing:

sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_* && sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server

I'm yet to figure out why they got corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a new set of keys with this on the client:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Take the contents of the public key from the client:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

And append them to the authorized keys file on the server:

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Permissions should look like this on the server:

```
-rw------- 1 user1 user1  399 Apr 20 09:04 authorized_keys
drwx------ 2 user1 user1 4096 Apr 20 09:04 .ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fatal: No supported key exchange algor...
```

Looks like the algorithms supported by your client differ from the ones supported by the server. Set up `LogLevel DEBUG` in server `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and use `ssh -vvv` to get more information why it fails.